# Pytorch change format of tensors from BxWxH to B, N, 3

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor A with the shape BxWxH (B=Batch size, W=Width, H=Height) and want to change it to a tensor B of shape BxNx3 (B=Batch size, N=Number of points=W*H).

Tensor A represents a depth map, e.g. tensor[0,1,2] => gives the depth value for the pixel (1,2) in batch 0.

Tensor B also represents a depth map but in a different format. Each point in tensor B has the following three dimensions: (x coord, y coord, depth value).

How can I transform tensor A into tensor B?

Comment: Are you sure it's `WxH` and not `HxW`?

Comment: Can also be HxW. That doesn't really matter in my case. The issue is to get from a 1d depth values to the 3d format (x, y, depth value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.meshgrid.html) to give you the `x` and `y` coordinates of each pixel:

```py
b, w, h = A.shape
x, y = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(w), torch.arange(h))
B = torch.cat((x[None, ...], y[None, ...], A), dim=0)
B = B.reshape(b, w*h, 3)
```